# Jsoup getting value of tag

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to try and read all the elements in the html and loop through and do stuff based on the the type of element.

I'm not having any luck, I can't find the proper method to check for the values of each element.

Any suggestions?

This is my latest attempt:

```
    Elements a = doc.getAllElements();

    for(Element e: a)
    {
        if( e.val().equals("td"))
        {
            System.out.println("TD");
        }
        else if(e.equals("tr"))
        {
            System.out.println("TR");
        }
    }
```

This does not print anything.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
Elements tdElements = doc.getElementsByTag("td");

for(Element element : tdElements )
{
     //Print the value of the element
     System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you select each element by its tags:

```
Elements tdTags = doc.select("td");
Elements trTags = doc.select("tr");

// Loop over all tdTags - you can do the same with trTags
for( Element element : tdTags )
{
    System.out.println(element); // print the element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

e.tag() will do that

```
Elements tdElements = doc.getElementsByTag("td");

for(Element element : tdElements )
{
    //Print the value of the element
    System.out.println(element.tag());
}
```